# Understanding quoting of strings in inline Lua code in Nginx+OpenResty

Tags: nginx, lua, quoting, openresty

For testing, I needed to create some fake data in an Nginx server with [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/). I needed to create an array where one IP address is replicated, for example:

```
 ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.4", ...]
```

In Ruby, an implementation could look like this:

```
 "[" + (["\"1.2.3.4\""] * 4096).join(", ") + "]"
```

I'm a beginner in Lua, and I struggled quite a lot to get it working in the OpenResty environment. This is what finally seems to work:

```
   content_by_lua '
        -- ... some code ...
        local ips = {}
        for i=1,4096 do ips[i] = "\\"1.2.3.4\\"" end
        local fakeData = table.concat(ips, ", ")
        local fakeResponse = "[" .. fakeData .. "]"
        --- ...
   '
```

I had some problems with the string quoting. First, I tried `'"1.2.3.4"'`, which did not work in the inline Lua section. That is understandable because the `'` character is already the separator for the `content_by_lua` section.

Next, I tried `"\"1.2.3.4\""`, which I would have expected to work, but it resulted in this (confusing) error:

```
failed to load inlined Lua code:
content_by_lua(nginx.conf:235):17: malformed number near '1.2.3.4'
```

By trial and error, I found out that this error goes away if you use double quoting (`"\\"1.2.3.4\\""`). This works in OpenResty, although the same code is rejected if I try it out in the [Lua REPL](https://github.com/hoelzro/lua-repl):

```
$ rep.lua 
Lua REPL 0.8
> "\\"1.2.3.4\\""
[string "REPL"]:1: unexpected symbol near '"\"'
```

To help me understand and become a better Lua/OpenResty programmer, I have some questions about quoting:

1. Why do you need double-quoting (in OpenResty)? (Why `"\\"1.2.3.4\\""` instead of `"\"1.2.3.4\""`?)
2. Why does OpenResty behave differently than the Lua REPL?
3. Is it possible to use single quotes in `content_by_lua` sections? (To simplify it to `'"1.2.3.4"'`)

---

(Also, an unrelated question that bothers me. Is there there a simpler way to express the code? When I compare it with my Ruby snippet, I'm quite sure that it can also be expressed much more elegantly in Lua.)

Comment: Probably, OpenResty applies its own backslash-deescaping phase before feeding your Lua block to Lua VM.  In other words, you need to do one more backslash-escaping compared to Lua REPL

Comment: In Lua block, you can use `string.char()` to make `'` or `"` without using backslash: `ips[i] = string.char(34).."1.2.3.4"..string.char(34)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Egor says, this is because the backslash character `\` is stripped out by the nginx config file parser before it is parsed by Lua. In your case, `"\\"1.2.3.4\\""` is correct, because it is parsed to `"\"1.2.3.4\""` by the nginx config parser, and then to the string `"1.2.3.4"` by Lua.

If you don't want to worry about how many backslashes to use, there are a couple of alternatives. The easiest is to use `content_by_lua_block`, which is available from OpenResty v0.9.17 onwards.

```
content_by_lua_block {
    -- ... some code ...
    local ips = {}
    for i=1,4096 do ips[i] = '"1.2.3.4"' end
    local fakeData = table.concat(ips, ", ")
    local fakeResponse = "[" .. fakeData .. "]"
    --- ...
}
```

If you can't use Lua blocks in your version of OpenResty, instead you can use Lua's [multiline string syntax](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial#Multiline%20quotes).

```
content_by_lua '
    -- ... some code ...
    local ips = {}
    for i=1,4096 do ips[i] = [["1.2.3.4"]] end
    local fakeData = table.concat(ips, ", ")
    local fakeResponse = "[" .. fakeData .. "]"
    --- ...
'
```

For more detail, see the [OpenResty docs](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/master/README.markdown#special-escaping-sequences).

Also, if you want to avoid working with tables at all, you can make the same test data by using `string.rep`.

```
content_by_lua '
    -- ... some code ...
    local ip = [["1.2.3.4"]]
    local fakeResponse = "[" .. string.rep(ip .. ", ", 4095) .. ip .. "]"
    --- ...
'
```